# Is there a bigger ship then the Panther Clipper (which can be bought) in Elite Frontier?

Tags: frontier-elite-2

I'm thinking about ships like the Lynx Bulk Carrier:

[image]

but I did not manage to buy one so far. So can I buy a bigger ship then the Panther Clipper?

Comment: Ships like the Lynx Bulk Carrier are too big to dock in a station, and would be unable to land on a planet. They're probably unloaded using smaller ships. In any case, they would be rather impractical for the player. I don't have any hard evidence, but I haven't encountered any ship bigger than the Panther Clipper. In fact, I've had trouble docking even with the Panther Clipper, it seems to scratch the hangar quite often (shields are essential :)).

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought as well.